# How to get key data on flutter?

Tags: http, flutter

how can I get the key data?
on my login widget, I already get the message but for the data, I still can't get it.
here the
[Source Code](https://pastebin.com/ckXMjNUQ)

I tried with this channel
here [a channel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x5wU6ZOFLpE&list=PLZQbl9Jhl-VACm40h5t6QMDB92WlopQmV&index=38)

```
JSON file
{
    "success": true,
    "message": "success",
    "data": [
        {
            "PROFILEUSERS_ID": "test000006",
            "USERNAME": "test",
            "NAMAUMKM": "Data Pertama",
            "email": "tes1@gmail.com",
            "STATUSUSER": "NARASUMBER"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: You can use [JSON to dart tool](https://app.quicktype.io/), which is available online for free. Paste your JSON to left panel and select dart language from upper right corner, You will get your dart class code, in which you can use methods like .toMap() and .toJson(), And it is very fast with less human error. This can be very helpful for huge JSON data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edid add demo code and demo picture**

Your LoginModel is below. and you can parse your json String with

```
final loginModel = loginModelFromJson(jsonString);
```

Login Model Class

```
// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final loginModel = loginModelFromJson(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

LoginModel loginModelFromJson(String str) => LoginModel.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String loginModelToJson(LoginModel data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class LoginModel {
    bool success;
    String message;
    List<Datum> data;

    LoginModel({
        this.success,
        this.message,
        this.data,
    });

    factory LoginModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => LoginModel(
        success: json["success"],
        message: json["message"],
        data: List<Datum>.from(json["data"].map((x) => Datum.fromJson(x))),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "success": success,
        "message": message,
        "data": List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())),
    };
}

class Datum {
    String profileusersId;
    String username;
    String namaumkm;
    String email;
    String statususer;

    Datum({
        this.profileusersId,
        this.username,
        this.namaumkm,
        this.email,
        this.statususer,
    });

    factory Datum.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Datum(
        profileusersId: json["PROFILEUSERS_ID"],
        username: json["USERNAME"],
        namaumkm: json["NAMAUMKM"],
        email: json["email"],
        statususer: json["STATUSUSER"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "PROFILEUSERS_ID": profileusersId,
        "USERNAME": username,
        "NAMAUMKM": namaumkm,
        "email": email,
        "STATUSUSER": statususer,
    };
}
```

demo code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart';

LoginModel loginModelFromJson(String str) => LoginModel.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String loginModelToJson(LoginModel data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class LoginModel {
  bool success;
  String message;
  List<Datum> data;

  LoginModel({
    this.success,
    this.message,
    this.data,
  });

  factory LoginModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => LoginModel(
    success: json["success"],
    message: json["message"],
    data: List<Datum>.from(json["data"].map((x) => Datum.fromJson(x))),
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "success": success,
    "message": message,
    "data": List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())),
  };
}

class Datum {
  String profileusersId;
  String username;
  String namaumkm;
  String email;
  String statususer;

  Datum({
    this.profileusersId,
    this.username,
    this.namaumkm,
    this.email,
    this.statususer,
  });

  factory Datum.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Datum(
    profileusersId: json["PROFILEUSERS_ID"],
    username: json["USERNAME"],
    namaumkm: json["NAMAUMKM"],
    email: json["email"],
    statususer: json["STATUSUSER"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "PROFILEUSERS_ID": profileusersId,
    "USERNAME": username,
    "NAMAUMKM": namaumkm,
    "email": email,
    "STATUSUSER": statususer,
  };
}


void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // is not restarted.
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the home page of your application. It is stateful, meaning
  // that it has a State object (defined below) that contains fields that affect
  // how it looks.

  // This class is the configuration for the state. It holds the values (in this
  // case the title) provided by the parent (in this case the App widget) and
  // used by the build method of the State. Fields in a Widget subclass are
  // always marked "final".

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    loadJson();
    setState(() {
      // This call to setState tells the Flutter framework that something has
      // changed in this State, which causes it to rerun the build method below
      // so that the display can reflect the updated values. If we changed
      // _counter without calling setState(), then the build method would not be
      // called again, and so nothing would appear to happen.
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // This method is rerun every time setState is called, for instance as done
    // by the _incrementCounter method above.
    //
    // The Flutter framework has been optimized to make rerunning build methods
    // fast, so that you can just rebuild anything that needs updating rather
    // than having to individually change instances of widgets.
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
        // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        // Center is a layout widget. It takes a single child and positions it
        // in the middle of the parent.
        child: Column(
          // Column is also layout widget. It takes a list of children and
          // arranges them vertically. By default, it sizes itself to fit its
          // children horizontally, and tries to be as tall as its parent.
          //
          // Invoke "debug painting" (press "p" in the console, choose the
          // "Toggle Debug Paint" action from the Flutter Inspector in Android
          // Studio, or the "Toggle Debug Paint" command in Visual Studio Code)
          // to see the wireframe for each widget.
          //
          // Column has various properties to control how it sizes itself and
          // how it positions its children. Here we use mainAxisAlignment to
          // center the children vertically; the main axis here is the vertical
          // axis because Columns are vertical (the cross axis would be
          // horizontal).
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }

  loadJson() async {
    //String fileText = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/help.html');
    String url = 'http://test.com/Android/json1.txt';
    Response response = await get(url);
    // sample info available in response

    String jsonString = response.body;

    LoginModel loginModel = loginModelFromJson(jsonString);

    print("${loginModel.data[0].profileusersId}");
    print("${loginModel.data[0].email}");
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: i still didn't get it,a whole code.sorry,cause im still practice use dart.
that code looks not familiar for me,there is any reference?
Thank You

Comment: ok sir,still trying with data post,and try to learning ,why have extra class from Login Model List<Datum>data.and then.why the respons in the LoginModel and Datum class have 2 factory.it like get the json object and parse to json and then parse again into json.
#sorry if my vacob to bad

Comment: In your json string contains two major structure for call api sucess or not and real data, so there are two factory.

Comment: ,now i get it.and for the post data i already combine with the [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WJxad_6IRUc&list=PLZQbl9Jhl-VACm40h5t6QMDB92WlopQmV&index=36).and my [SC](https://pastebin.com/E5jJ0evJ).now i can move to shared_preferences
thank #chunchunghan & #Devarsh Ranpara